# Google sheets formula returning “Formula parse error”

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Not sure why my formula isn't working

It’s super simple but yet returns a formula parse error

```
=If(A19>A22, “no”, “yes”)
```

Value of A19 is 30 and the value of A22 is 0

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
=IF(A19>A22; "no"; "yes")
```

[image]

instead of **`“ ”`** you need to use **`" "`**