# Formula parse error on importrange query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to recreate what's happening in this video at 7:17
https://youtu.be/5S7laJS9meU?t=437

I want to merge two sheets and remove the empty rows.

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(L2 ,"sheet1!A2:F20");IMPORTRANGE(L3 ,"sheet2!A2:F20")},"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

I've tested with importing from each sheet individually and given access to the document for both of them, and they work fine. What am I doing wrong when trying to merge?

Comment: Welcome. Please check your sheet's locale.

Comment: @marikamitsos All sheets have same the same locale.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a virtual array within the curly brackets but not "prepped" the formula for that. Try wrapping the entire thing in `ArrayFormula(...)`:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(L2 ,"sheet1!A2:F20");IMPORTRANGE(L3 ,"sheet2!A2:F20")},"select * where Col1 is not null"))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It still returns formula parse error even if i write exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Without seeing the sheet, I'm afraid guessing is as far as things can go. If you'd like to share a link, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor," I'll be happy to take a look. It's the only we can see the IMPORTRANGE in action; even making a copy of a "View only" sheet will disconnect the other sheets without the proper permissions to reconnect them.

Comment: I will add two questions here: 1.) What EXACTLY is typed into L2 and L3? -and- 2.) What is your international locale and language setting?

Comment: Oh my gosh it was something as simple as the language setting changing the actual names of the functions, since I had the document locales set to my own country. I had no idea the functions would actually have translated versions depending on the locale!

Comment: Well, I'm glad the additional questions led to a solution!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I'm a dummy and didn't know that the locale setting changes what language the functions are in. I had the documents set to my own country but was using the english function names!

Comment: The problem is not the language of the function but the decimal separator. Rel. [Google sheets formula returning “Formula parse error”](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119543/88163)

Comment: Related [Why is Google Sheets documentation falsely using commas to separate parameters?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99938/88163)